# How can I replace these two functions with a single function?

Tags: python, function, numpy

I have the following two functions:

```
def predict(self, X):
    y_pred = [self._predict(x) for x in X]
    return np.array(y_pred)

def _predict(self, x):
    probs = []
    for idx, c in enumerate(self.classes):
        prior = self.classesPrior[idx]
        probs_c = np.sum(np.log(self.density_function(x, idx, self.classesMean[idx], self.classesVariance[idx])))
        probs.append(probs_c + np.log(prior))
    return self.classes[np.argmax(probs)]
```

I am trying to compose this code into a function named `predict` that has the same behavior as observed when using the above two functions.

This is what I tried to do:

```
def predict(self, X):
    probs = []
    # calculate posterior probability for each class
    for idx, c in enumerate(self.classes):
        prior = self.classesPrior[idx]
        for x in X:
            probs_c = np.sum(np.log(self.density_function(x, idx, self.classesMean[idx], self.classesVariance[idx])))
            probs.append(np.argmax(probs_c + np.log(prior)))

    y_pred = self.classes[probs]
    # return class with highest posterior probability
    return np.array(y_pred)
```

Comment: The first code isn't correct either. Is the second function supposed to be nested inside the first one, or are they two separate functions? The indendation is ambiguous and invalid.

Comment: BTW you are trying to do the opposite of composing two functions. You are trying to write *one* function that does the same thing as two.

Comment: Why do you think that the second code is not correct?

Comment: "I am trying to composite only one function" it's hard to see from this example what you're trying to do. It sounds like you only need one function, why are there two?

Comment: As a refresher, please read [ask]. "But this is not correct." That is not a *question*; please ask one. You should also make sure it is clear: what *is* correct? What should happen when you run the code? What does happen, and *how is that different*? Then you can ask a *specific* question that starts with a question word like "how" or "why" and ends with a question mark (`?`), and makes it clear *what help you need in order to solve the problem*.

Comment: shouldn't the loop over `self.classes` be nested in the loop over `X`? I guess you're trying to use numpy vectorization, but without knowing what `self.density_function` is, which uses `idx` parameter in loop, can't really say if that's possible

Comment: As a hint, though: since `self._predict(x) for x in X` is the first thing that is encountered in the original code, that directly tells you that `for x in X:` should be the **outer** loop, and any loop needed for the `self._predict(x)` work should be an **inner** loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the list comprehension and use a `for` loop instead, placing the function definition of `_predict()` inside the `for` loop with minor modifications:

```py
def predict(self, X):
    y_pred = []
    
    for x in X:
        probs = []
        for idx, c in enumerate(self.classes):
            prior = self.classesPrior[idx]
            probs_c = np.sum(np.log(self.density_function(x, idx, self.classesMean[idx], self.classesVariance[idx])))
            probs.append(probs_c + np.log(prior))
        y_pred.append(self.classes[np.argmax(probs)])
        
    return np.array(y_pred)
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really composition, as @mkriger1 pointed out, but if all you want is to "unroll" the list comprehension and inline the function, you could do the following:

Keep in mind that the list comprehension `y_pred = [something(x) for x in X]` is equivalent to the code

```py
y_pred = []
for x in X:
    y_pred.append(something(x))
```

Therefore, you could do

```py
def predict(self, X):
    y_pred = []  # Initialize y_pred
    for x in X:  # Iterate over 'X'
        # Here we repeat the content of _predict
        probs = []
        for idx, c in enumerate(self.classes):
            prior = self.classesPrior[idx]
            probs_c = np.sum(np.log(
                self.density_function(
                    x, idx,
                    self.classesMean[idx],
                    self.classesVariance[idx]
                )
            ))
            probs.append(probs_c + np.log(prior))
        # Finally we append what _predict was previously returning
        y_pred.append(self.classes[np.argmax(probs))
    return np.array(y_pred)
```

Comment: Thank you, @kalil Cabral! In fact, I don't want to use `_predict()` instead I want to create only one function called `predict()` using both `predict()` and `_predict` contents.

Comment: @Joe Updated to match that! Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: You have a syntax error in your first loop `for for x in X`... otherwise looks great.

Comment: Oops, thanks for pointing that out, @TobiahRex